# SendGrid Add Category to mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid, and I want to add one or more category to the email, but the added category hadn't been sent!

This is the code:

```
internal class Example
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Execute().Wait();
    }

    static async Task Execute()
    {
        //FYI, the following three variables are not real
        var apiKey = "SG.XXX";
        var fromEmail = "";
        var toEmail = "";

        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress(fromEmail);
        var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
        var to = new EmailAddress(toEmail);
        var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
        var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        msg.AddHeader("category", "cat1"); //This line does nothing!
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which library are you using to send the emails?

Comment: I downloaded this repo https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp and added my ApiKey and worked on it

Comment: The `MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail` returns a `SendGridMessage` object which has a property for `Categories`.  See - https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/src/SendGrid/Helpers/Mail/SendGridMessage.cs.  You should be able to assign to this property for the categories to work.  Though I do agree that the header should work, it might be overridden by the property depending on how the library generates the request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks [Kami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1603275/kami), I tried your answer and it worked properly.

I replaced this line `msg.AddHeader("category", "cat1");` with `msg.AddCategory("cat1");`